# Setup of ember-service-worker-cache-fallback to sync data

Tags: api, caching, ember.js, service-worker, background-sync

I'm a beginner in ember and service workers. My goal is to setup a simple ember app that works offline. I basically have a list of elements that are available through an API (GET/POST).

When I'm online, everything works as expected. I can GET the list and POST new items. When I'm offline the app works, but network requests are not executed once I go back online. All network requests are actually executed while I'm offline (and obviously fail). I would expect that the service worker caches the network requests and executes them only once I'm back online. Is this wrong?

Here some information about my setup:

Ember version:

- ember-cli: 2.13.1
- node: 7.10.0
- os: darwin x64

Service Worker Add-ons (as listed in app/package.json):

```
"ember-service-worker": "^0.6.6",
"ember-service-worker-asset-cache": "^0.6.1",
"ember-service-worker-cache-fallback": "^0.6.1",
"ember-service-worker-index": "^0.6.1",
```

I should probably also mention that I use ember-django-adapter in version 1.1.3.

This is my app/ember-cli-build.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'esw-cache-fallback': {
      // RegExp patterns specifying which URLs to cache.
      patterns: [
        'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/(.*)',
      ],

      // changing this version number will bust the cache
      version: '1'
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

My network requests (GET/POST) go to http://localhost:8000/api/v1/properties/.

This is my app/adapters/applications.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {

  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://localhost:8000',
  authorizer: 'authorizer:token',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
  return this._super(type, id, record) + '/';
  }
});
```

The service worker registers when I open the app:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  self.addEventListener('install', function installEventListenerCallback(event) {
      return self.skipWaiting();
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function installEventListenerCallback(event) {
      return self.clients.claim();
    });

  const FILES = ['assets/connect.css', 'assets/connect.js', 'assets/connect.map', 'assets/failed.png', 'assets/passed.png', 'assets/test-support.css', 'assets/test-support.js', 'assets/test-support.map', 'assets/tests.js', 'assets/tests.map', 'assets/vendor.css', 'assets/vendor.js', 'assets/vendor.map'];
  const PREPEND = undefined;
  const VERSION$1 = '1';
  const REQUEST_MODE = 'cors';

  /*
   * Deletes all caches that start with the `prefix`, except for the
   * cache defined by `currentCache`
   */
  var cleanupCaches = (prefix, currentCache) => {
    return caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      cacheNames.forEach((cacheName) => {
        let isOwnCache = cacheName.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
        let isNotCurrentCache = cacheName !== currentCache;

        if (isOwnCache && isNotCurrentCache) {
          caches.delete(cacheName);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const CACHE_KEY_PREFIX = 'esw-asset-cache';
  const CACHE_NAME = `${CACHE_KEY_PREFIX}-${VERSION$1}`;
  const CACHE_URLS = FILES.map((file) => {
    return new URL(file, (PREPEND || self.location)).toString();
  });

  /*
   * Removes all cached requests from the cache that aren't in the `CACHE_URLS`
   * list.
   */
  const PRUNE_CURRENT_CACHE = () => {
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
      return cache.keys().then((keys) => {
        keys.forEach((request) => {
          if (CACHE_URLS.indexOf(request.url) === -1) {
            cache.delete(request);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  };

  self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches
        .open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then((cache) => {
          return Promise.all(CACHE_URLS.map((url) => {
            let request = new Request(url, { mode: REQUEST_MODE });
            return fetch(request)
              .then((response) => {
                if (response.status >= 400) {
                  throw new Error(`Request for ${url} failed with status ${response.statusText}`);
                }
                return cache.put(url, response);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.error(`Not caching ${url} due to ${error}`);
              });
          }));
        })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
      Promise.all([
        cleanupCaches(CACHE_KEY_PREFIX, CACHE_NAME),
        PRUNE_CURRENT_CACHE()
      ])
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    let isGETRequest = event.request.method === 'GET';
    let shouldRespond = CACHE_URLS.indexOf(event.request.url) !== -1;

    if (isGETRequest && shouldRespond) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request, { cacheName: CACHE_NAME })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response) {
              return response;
            }
            return fetch(event.request);
          })
      );
    }
  });

  const VERSION$2 = '1';
  const PATTERNS = ['http://localhost:8000/api/v1/(.*)'];

  /**
   * Create an absolute URL, allowing regex expressions to pass
   *
   * @param {string} url
   * @param {string|object} baseUrl
   * @public
   */
  function createNormalizedUrl(url, baseUrl = self.location) {
    return decodeURI(new URL(encodeURI(url), baseUrl).toString());
  }

  /**
   * Create an (absolute) URL Regex from a given string
   *
   * @param {string} url
   * @returns {RegExp}
   * @public
   */
  function createUrlRegEx(url) {
    let normalized = createNormalizedUrl(url);
    return new RegExp(`^${normalized}$`);
  }

  /**
   * Check if given URL matches any pattern
   *
   * @param {string} url
   * @param {array} patterns
   * @returns {boolean}
   * @public
   */
  function urlMatchesAnyPattern(url, patterns) {
    return !!patterns.find((pattern) => pattern.test(decodeURI(url)));
  }

  const CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$1 = 'esw-cache-fallback';
  const CACHE_NAME$1 = `${CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$1}-${VERSION$2}`;

  const PATTERN_REGEX = PATTERNS.map(createUrlRegEx);

  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    let request = event.request;
    if (request.method !== 'GET' || !/^https?/.test(request.url)) {
      return;
    }

    if (urlMatchesAnyPattern(request.url, PATTERN_REGEX)) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME$1).then((cache) => {
          return fetch(request)
            .then((response) => {
              cache.put(request, response.clone());
              return response;
            })
            .catch(() => caches.match(event.request));
        })
      );
    }
  });

  self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(cleanupCaches(CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$1, CACHE_NAME$1));
  });

  const VERSION$3 = '1';
  const INDEX_HTML_PATH = 'index.html';

  const CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$2 = 'esw-index';
  const CACHE_NAME$2 = `${CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$2}-${VERSION$3}`;

  const INDEX_HTML_URL = new URL(INDEX_HTML_PATH, self.location).toString();

  self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
      fetch(INDEX_HTML_URL, { credentials: 'include' }).then((response) => {
        return caches
          .open(CACHE_NAME$2)
          .then((cache) => cache.put(INDEX_HTML_URL, response));
      })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(cleanupCaches(CACHE_KEY_PREFIX$2, CACHE_NAME$2));
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    let request = event.request;
    let isGETRequest = request.method === 'GET';
    let isHTMLRequest = request.headers.get('accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1;
    let isLocal = new URL(request.url).origin === location.origin

    if (isGETRequest && isHTMLRequest && isLocal) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.match(INDEX_HTML_URL, { cacheName: CACHE_NAME$2 })
      );
    }
  });

}());
```

This is how network requests appear in Chrome:[Network request while offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClyMM.png)

I assume the problem is in the configuration of ember-service-worker-cache-fallback. But I'm not quite sure about that. Any idea or link to a working example is welcome. I didn't find a lot about ember-service-worker-cache-fallback so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't worked much with Service Workers yet but your screenshot of network tab in dev tools looks good to me. App is making a request, which fails (first entry) and Service Worker steps in with cached version (second entry). What do you mean by network request should be executed when you are back only? As far as I understood ember-service-worker-cache-fallback caches successful request and provide them as fallback if network request fail. Refreshing records after network connection is working again seems to be out of scope.

Comment: Thanks jelhan. Then I misunderstood the scope of ember-service-worker-cache-fallback. Do you have any idea how I could cache requests (e.g. POST requests for when I add a new item) and execute them once I'm back online?

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is the correct and expected behaviour of ember-service-worker-cache-fallback, that is first try fetch from the network if not possible then fallback to fetch from the cached version in the service worker.

I believe what you are looking for is some kind of queuing mechanism for failed requests. This is not covered in the scope of ember-service-worker-cache-fallback.

Fear not though, I had similar ambitions and came up with my own solution called [ember-service-worker-enqueue](https://github.com/campus-discounts/ember-service-worker-enqueue) . It's a ember-service-worker plugin that queues only failed mutation requests eg POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE using Mozilla's Localforage and then sends them when the network is stable.

It's perfect for protecting you ember app against network failures or server errors which respond with 5xx status codes.

NOTE: In my experience, Service Workers are best when treated on a per use case, so don't blindly install my plugin and expect things to work the same way for you, rather go through the heavily commented code ( < 200 lines), fork the plugin and adjust it to fit your needs. Enjoy,

Ps: I'm also working on another one called [ember-service-worker-push-notifications](https://github.com/campus-discounts/ember-service-worker-push-notifications) still early days but will follow same heavy comments for anyone looking to gain from it. Cheers!